# Java Apache2 Log File Permission Denied

Tags: java-8, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, nio2

I'm trying to read the apache2 custom log files in the /var/log/apache2/my_site/access.log in a Java program. But i get a permission denied Excpetion.

The code is working on the Winows OS, i can read the log file, but in Ubuntu, i cannot access the apache2 log files in the JVM. This is the output

[image: output]

The permissions snapshot

[image]

So how can i adjust the file permissions that i can read the file and Apache 2 still can write to it?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Comment: i already know that. But how can i adjust it, i have tomcat, tomcat7, www-data groups.The file owner is root, other is root. How can modify the permissions so that Apache2 still can write logs and JVM can read the file content

Comment: Since other has read access the JVM should be able to read access.log. However, it might be that the JVM also needs search permission (x) for the *directories* in the path to access.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the folder of the log file outside the /var/log/apache2 folder.
Apache2 and JVM can both access the file in RW mode.